# Is there a way hide database's map data when displaying entire map to a user

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, xml, google-maps

I am building a website that allows users to find locations and areas around the world based on data other users will be allowed to submit. I have a database containing all of the location data, latitudes and longitudes.
I have implemented the Google Maps Javascript API, as well as the Static API for simple things in the website. What I would like to do is allow users to view all of the database's map points on a world map for the user to drag and zoom to the different areas to view and select a pin for  more information about that location.

There is an example on Google's site that shows how to do something like this [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3). But what if I'd like to hide this data from the client, rather than passing to them an entire XML file with all locations?

I supposed what I would like to do is make it more difficult for someone to intercept all of the coordinates and save them to their computer. This might be a subjective question because of my novice understanding of this and I understand it is probably a trade-off type situation.

Comment: An option would to serve your data as map tiles rather than Google Maps markers, Polygons, Polygons, etc.; but that is (a lot) more complicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically, you don't want to make it easy for someone to take all your data at once?

A fairly straight-forward strategy for this would be to provide search and filter controls that interact with discrete apis (ajax services). You could have an API that provides summary data about how many points are in one area and provide guided search constraints to let the user drill down further.

You could then only return concrete data points once the user gets to a specific level of depth.

Does that help?

Comment: Actually, yes. I think that would be a great solution. Something this simple has been bugging me for weeks.. You mention apis; I wouldn't mind coding my own, but are there any existing apis that come to mind for something like this?

Comment: It depends on what your architecture is...what are you using server-side? for example, what database are you using for the user supplied data points?

Comment: I am using a MySql database.

Comment: hmm...i'm not aware of anything out-of-the-box for php/mysql. would be interested if you find something...